# ggsurvplot_facet returns: "Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name" when used inside a function

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, survival-analysis, color-palette

I'm trying to plot survival curves for several variables facet by the variable sex with the ggsurvplot_facet() function. When I apply my code to a single fitted model, it works fine. However, when I try to use the same code within a function or within a for loop, it fails to plot all the survival curves that should be plotted and returns an error. I would perform this plotting in ggsurvplot_facet() itself if it allowed as input a list of survfit elements, in the same way ggsurvplot() does, but ggsurvplot_facet() only allows for a single survfit element at a time.

I'm running my code in RStudio in a 2018 MacBook Pro with Mac OS High Sierra.

Consider the following dataset: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01704535336107726906

It contains the observations for several visits for 100 subjects and 4 different variables. Two of the variables (variable1 and variable2) can have two different values (0 or 1) and the two other variables (variable3 and variable4) can have three different values (0, 1 or 2).

I have started to work with the ones that can have two different values and I have written the following code:

```
# Load libraries
require(mgcv)
require(msm)
library(dplyr)
library(grDevices)
library(survival)
library(survminer)


# Set working directory
dirname<-dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)
setwd(dirname)


load("ggsurvplot_facet_error.rda")


fit_test <- survfit(
  Surv(follow_up, as.numeric(status)) ~ (sex + variable1), data = data)

plot_test <- ggsurvplot_facet(fit_test,
                                     data = data,
                                     pval = TRUE,
                                     conf.int = TRUE,
                                     surv.median.line = "hv", # Specify median survival
                                     break.time.by = 1,
                                     facet.by = "sex",
                                     ggtheme = theme_bw(), # Change ggplot2 theme
                                     palette = "aaas",
                                     legend = "bottom",
                                     xlab = "Time (years)",
                                     ylab = "Death probability",
                                     panel.labs = list(sex_recoded=c("Male", "Female")),
                                     legend.labs = c("A", "B")
) 

plot_test
```

This code works great and generates the following plot:

[image]

However, when I try to convert this code into a function or a FOR loop, so that it applies the same code to variable1 and variable2, I always get an error with the color/palette part of the plotting step.

```
# Variables_with_2_categories:  variable1 and variable2
two <- c("variable1", "variable2")

## TEST #1: USING A FUNCTION

fit_plot_function <- function(x) {

# FIT part of the function
  two.i <- two[i]

fit_temp <- survfit(Surv(as.numeric(follow_up), as.numeric(status)) ~ 
                        sex + eval(as.name(paste0(two.i))), data = data)

# PLOT part of the function
  plot_temp <- ggsurvplot_facet(fit_temp,
                                data = data,
                                pval = TRUE,
                                conf.int = TRUE,
                                surv.median.line = "hv", # Specify median survival
                                break.time.by = 1,
                                facet.by = "sex",
                                ggtheme = theme_bw(), # Change ggplot2 theme
                                palette = "aaas",
                                legend = "bottom",
                                xlab = "Time (years)",
                                ylab = "Death probability",
                                panel.labs = list(sex_recoded=c("Male", "Female")),
                                legend.labs = rep(c("A", "B"),2)
  ) 
}


fit_plot_function(two)
# Warning message:
#  Now, to change color palette, use the argument palette= 
#  'eval(as.name(paste0(two.i)))' instead of color = 'eval(as.name(paste0(two.i)))' 

print(plot_temp)

# Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : 
#  invalid color name 'eval(as.name(paste0(two.i)))'
```

It looks like when it evaluates the names of the variables that were parsed with a vector, it doesn't recognize the variable names. With a FOR loop it happens exactly the same:

```
## TEST #2: USING A FOR LOOP

n.two <- length(two)

for(i in 1:n.two) {
  two.i <- two[i]

  fit_temp <- survfit(Surv(as.numeric(follow_up), as.numeric(status)) ~ 
                        (sex + eval(as.name(paste0(two.i)))), data = data)



  plot_temp <- ggsurvplot_facet(fit_temp,
                                data = data,
                                pval = TRUE,
                                conf.int = TRUE,
                                surv.median.line = "hv", # Specify median survival
                                break.time.by = 1,
                                facet.by = "sex",
                                ggtheme = theme_bw(), # Change ggplot2 theme
                                palette = "aaas",
                                legend = "bottom",
                                xlab = "Time (years)",
                                ylab = "Death probability",
                                panel.labs = list(sex_recoded=c("Male", "Female")),
                                legend.labs = rep(c("A", "B"),2)
    ) 
}

print(plot_temp)

# ERROR: Now, to change color palette, use the argument palette= 'eval(as.name(paste0(two.i)))' 
# instead of color = 'eval(as.name(paste0(two.i)))
```

Just as an additional comment, it would be great if I could apply the same code to the variables that have both, two or three different values at the same time, instead of having to apply a different function for each of them.

Thank you very much for your help,

Best Regards,

Yatrosin

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] survminer_0.4.3.999 ggpubr_0.2          magrittr_1.5        ggplot2_3.1.1       survival_2.44-1.1  
[6] dplyr_0.8.0.1       msm_1.6.7           mgcv_1.8-27         nlme_3.1-137       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        pillar_1.3.1      compiler_3.5.1    plyr_1.8.4        tools_3.5.1       digest_0.6.18    
 [7] tibble_2.1.1      gtable_0.3.0      lattice_0.20-38   pkgconfig_2.0.2   rlang_0.3.4       Matrix_1.2-17    
[13] ggsci_2.9         rstudioapi_0.10   cmprsk_2.2-7      yaml_2.2.0        mvtnorm_1.0-10    expm_0.999-4     
[19] xfun_0.6          gridExtra_2.3     knitr_1.22        withr_2.1.2       survMisc_0.5.5    generics_0.0.2   
[25] grid_3.5.1        tidyselect_0.2.5  data.table_1.12.2 glue_1.3.1        KMsurv_0.1-5      R6_2.4.0         
[31] km.ci_0.5-2       purrr_0.3.2       tidyr_0.8.3       scales_1.0.0      backports_1.1.4   splines_3.5.1    
[37] assertthat_0.2.1  xtable_1.8-3      colorspace_1.4-1  labeling_0.3      lazyeval_0.2.2    munsell_0.5.0    
[43] broom_0.5.2       crayon_1.3.4      zoo_1.8-5
```

Comment: The problem may be related to this prior post: https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/342 . However, even if I use the survminer::surv_fit() fx instead of the survival::survfit() fx to generate my fitted model, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's time to purrrify. What you want can be done with `purrr`. You can read about making ggplot2 `purrr` [here](https://www.brodrigues.co/blog/2017-03-29-make-ggplot2-purrr/) and more examples [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/).

First of all we need to transform your data to long format with `tidyr::gather`. We'll keep everything in data frame as it was except variables1,2,3,4. They will be melt.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>% 
  gather(num, variable, -sample_id,  -sex,
         -visit_number, -age_at_enrollment,
         -follow_up, -status) %>% 
  mutate(num2 = num) %>% # We'll need this column later for the titles
  as_tibble() -> long_data


# A tibble: 2,028 x 8
   sample_id   sex    visit_number age_at_enrollment follow_up status num       variable
   <fct>       <fct>  <fct>                    <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>  <chr>        <int>
 1 sample_0001 Female 1                         56.7     0     1      variable1        0
 2 sample_0001 Female 2                         57.7     0.920 1      variable1        0
 3 sample_0001 Female 3                         58.6     1.90  1      variable1        0
 4 sample_0001 Female 4                         59.7     2.97  2      variable1        0
 5 sample_0001 Female 5                         60.7     4.01  1      variable1        0
 6 sample_0001 Female 6                         61.7     4.99  1      variable1        0
 7 sample_0002 Female 1                         55.9     0     1      variable1        1
 8 sample_0002 Female 2                         56.9     1.04  1      variable1        1
 9 sample_0002 Female 3                         58.0     2.15  1      variable1        1
10 sample_0002 Female 4                         59.0     3.08  1      variable1        1
# ... with 2,018 more rows
```

Now we need to transform our long dataframe to a nested dataframe and `map`! Be accurate with `ggsurvplot` — this function doesn't support `tibbles` which are creating during `nest()`.

```
long_data %>% 
  group_by(num) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    # Run survfit() for every variable
    fit_f = map(data, ~survfit(Surv(follow_up, as.numeric(status)) ~ (sex + variable), data = .)),
    # Create survplot for every variable and survfit
    plots = map2(fit_f, data, ~ggsurvplot(.x,
                                          as.data.frame(.y), # Important! convert from tibble to data.frame 
                                          pval = TRUE,
                                          conf.int = TRUE,
                                          facet.by = "sex",
                                          surv.median.line = "hv", 
                                          break.time.by = 1,
                                          ggtheme = theme_bw(),
                                          palette = "aaas",
                                          xlab = "Time (years)",
                                          ylab = "Death probability") +
                   ggtitle(paste0("This is plot of ", .y$num2)) + # Add a title
                   theme(legend.position = "bottom"))) -> plots
```

Now you can return your plots by typing this:

```
plots$plots[[1]]
plots$plots[[2]]
plots$plots[[3]] 
plots$plots[[4]] # plotted below
```

[image]

And save all your plots using `map2()`

```
map2(paste0(unique(long_data$num), ".pdf"), plots$plots, ggsave)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to change legend labels. The only solution I can suggest is below. Remember that `plots$plots[[…]]` is a `ggplot` object, so you can change everything after. For example, to change legend labels I just need to add `scale_fill_discrete` and `scale_color_discrete`. The same can be done with the title, labs, theme etc.

```
library(ggsci) # to add aaas color palette

plots$plots[[3]] +
  labs(title = "Variable 3",
       subtitle = "You just have to be the best") +
  ggsci::scale_color_aaas(guide = F) +
  ggsci::scale_fill_aaas(label = LETTERS[1:3])
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @atsyplenkov, maybe this is a matter of another question, but how would you modify the code so that it shows up the title for each of the plots ("variable1", "variable2"...) and how would you modify the legend labels considering that there are two types of plots: the ones that contain two categories ("A", "B") and the ones that contain 3 categories ("A", "B", "C")? The legend issue was part of the original post. I feel purrrifyng hard for now. Thanks

Comment: @Yatrosin, unfortunately I cannot figure out how to change the legend labels. It's very tricky cause the labels amount is changing. To add a title, just add after a `ggsurvplot` a `ggtitle` function wih `+` as it was a ordinary `ggplot2`. I've also create a new column `num2` equal to `num`. See the answer.

Comment: I had tried the .y$num for the title before, but I always get the following error, both for the .y$num or .y$num2: ````Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'num'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'num'. 
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'num'. 
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'num'.````

Comment: Did you create a `.y$num2`? Try to restart R and run the code from my answer one more time.

Comment: Dear @Yatrosin, seems to me that the easiest way will be to convert `0, 1, 2` to `("A", "B", "C")` afterwards. To add manually to a `plots$plots[[…]]`. For example, for `variable 3` it would be like: `plots$plots[[3]] +
  ggsci::scale_color_aaas(guide = F) +
  ggsci::scale_fill_aaas(label = LETTERS[1:3])`. I'm using a `ggsci` package for color palette, don't forget to install it.

Comment: @Yatrosin, did you try to change legend labels and title?

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll be able to assess the problem if I split my variables into two dataframes, one containing the ones that have 2 categories and the other one with the variables that have three categories.